# Uploading images into database in xampp through import

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to upload images through 'import' in my database in phpMyAdmin panel in xampp. The text for uloading looks like this:
*File may be compressed (gzip, bzip2, zip) or uncompressed.
A compressed file's name must end in .[format].[compression]. Example: .sql.zip
Browse your computer:(Max: 128MiB)*

When i'm trying to upload .zip or .jpeg, it gives me this error:

*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '???' at line 1*

I'm looking for a way to upload images to the database for banner purpose, to display from the database, therefore i'm trying to avoid coding to import my images to the database but instead using the import.

Comment: Show us the code and your SQL statement for knowing the problem better. Plus, uploading images to a database is a bad idea..

Comment: Better to save image path(name) to database.

Answer (score 1):

In PhpMyAdmin "IMPORT" tab is for importing SQL syntax, you can't upload image here. Use "INSERT" to add information to table. Also, save only file name in database while file itself will be saved on server.

Comment: Does that mean that I CAN insert images in my image column with INSERT? In that case, what would be an example for filling in 'function' and 'value' in my image column?

Comment: @OdJacobsen You can only insert string in database. So if you have bas64 string of image, than yes, otherwise, no, you can't have image itself in database.